# If the equation $Ax = b$ is consitent, can the equation have more than one solution for some $b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following task:

> If $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix and the equation $Ax = b$ is consistent for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^5$, is it possible that the equation has more than one solution? Why or why not?

I answered the following, but I am not sure if my statements are true. If they are false, I ask you to point it out and elaborate. If they are true, I ask you to elaborate as to why they are true. I will numerate each statement I am insecure about.

> Seeing as $A$ is quadratic, it may or may not be invertible. If it is invertible, we have $A^{-1}(Ax) = A^{-1}b = x$ as a unique solution. (1)  (This follows directly from an invertible matrix being row equivalent to the identity matrix, correct?) If $A$ is not invertible, we know that the equation has several solutions, seeing as $A$ is not row equivalent to the identity matrix, and thus may or may not have free variables. (2)

I am really insecure about (2). We are told that the equation $Ax = b$ is consistent for every $b \in \mathbb{R}^5$. Does this imply that we have only one of the following two alternatives:

1. $A$ is invertible and we have the unique solution $A^{-1}b$
2. $A$ is not invertible and we have infinitely many solutions.

If so, why?

Comment: Although matrices can represent quadratic forms, that is not at issue here.  So saying $A$ is "quadratic" is a possible source of confusion for your Reader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, case 2 can never happen.  If you have at least one solution for all $b$, then $A$ must be invertible.  You can solve $Ax=b$ for a basis and use linearity to prove this.  Conversely, if $A$ is not invertible, its image is less than the full space, its kernel is more than the origin, and some $b$ will not permit a solution of $Ax=b$

Comment: I am not familiar with the term "kernel", seeing as I recently started the course. If I understand you correctly, seeing as every $b \in \mathbb{R}^5$ gives a solution, we need $A$ to be invertible. If not, for some $b$, the system will be inconsistent (Row operations will give us a contradiction of the likes $0 = a$ for $a \ne 0$.) Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.  The kernel of a matrix $A$ is the set of vectors it sends to $0$.  It is a subspace of the whole space.  The [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank-nullity_theorem) says the dimension of the image plus the dimension of the kernel is the dimension of the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

If $Ax=b$ is a square system, then being consistent for every $b$ implies $A$ is invertible, so the solution would be unique for every $b$ as well.

If $A$ were not square but had full row rank, then there would be a solution for every $b$ and this solution would never be unique since having more columns than rows implies the homogeneous problem has more than one solution.